# Change the legend's language with qtm tmap

Tags: r, maps, tmap

I try to make a simple choropleth map using *tmap* :

```
library(tmap)

data(World, rivers, metro)
qtm(World, fill="HPI", fill.n=9, fill.palette="div", fill.auto.palette.mapping=FALSE, 
 fill.title="Happy Planet Index", fill.id="name", format="World", style="gray")
```

I would like to update the legend: instead of `"20 to 25"`, I would like to get `"20-25"` or `"20 à 25"`.

I haven't found the parameter that would let me choose this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use `text.separator` in `tm_layout`, see below:

```
qtm(World, fill="HPI", fill.n=9, fill.palette="div", fill.auto.palette.mapping=FALSE, 
    fill.title="Happy Planet Index", fill.id="name", format="World", style="gray",
    text.separator="-") +
  tm_layout(legend.format = list(text.separator = "-"))
```